# Nestjs: cannot inject ConfigService while testing

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, jestjs, nestjs, typeorm

I'm having problems setting up a unit test that utilizes the `ConfigService` to set up TypeORM. The test below fails with the following message:

> Nest can't resolve dependencies of the TypeOrmModuleOptions (?).
> Please make sure that the argument ConfigService at index [0] is
> available in the TypeOrmCoreModule context.

I've tried adding the `ConfigService` as a provider, but with no luck. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

```
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { Test } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { TypeOrmModule, TypeOrmModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

describe('TypeORM setup', () => {
    beforeEach(async () => {
        await Test.createTestingModule({
            providers: [ConfigService],
            imports: [
                ConfigModule.forRoot(),
                TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
                    useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => ({ ...config.get('db') }),
                    inject: [ConfigService],
                }),
            ],
        }).compile();
    });

    it('dummy', () => {
        true === true;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You either need to set `{ isGlobal: true }` as an option for the `ConfigModule` or you need to add `imports: [ConfigModule]` to the `TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync()` configuration